# Como fazer o UserControl preencher todo o TabPage

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Estou colocando um UserControl dentro de um TabPage. Quando não esta Maximizado, o UserControl preenche todo TabControl

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, se eu maximizar a tela, fica um espaço a direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei usercontrol winforms "Anchor" ou propriedade "Dock". Então eu tentei o seguinte

```
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
control.Dock = AutoScaleMode.None
```

Já tentei também, mas ele só centraliza o Usercontrol.

```
control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
control.Left = (tab.Width - control.Width) / 2
control.Top = (tab.Height - control.Height) / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você edita alguma propriedade como `Control.Top` ou `Control.Anchor` a propriedade `Dock` será descartada. Convém editar apenas a propriedade `Dock` do controle, nada mais.

```
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Caso você mecha na propriedade `Anchor` após a `Dock`, a colagem será descartada.